# Selecting element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many forms in my webpage with the same class-name.

```
<form method="post" action="" class="like-form">
    <input type="hidden" value="10"/>
    <!--some other input tags -->
    <input type="submit" value="like" class="btn btn-primary like"/>
</form>
```

What I want to do is:
Whenever I hit a like button, I want to get the data of the form (containing this 'like' button) by doing something like:

```
$(".like").click(function(event) {      
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).prev(".like-form").serialize();
    console.log(formData);
});
```

But this doesn't work. How can I achieve this in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `closest()` instead of `prev()`.

```
var formData = $(this).closest(".like-form").serialize();
```